# If not in IP list, use http_basic

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-security

Is it possible to make it so Symfony will ask for http_basic authentification only if the client IP isn't in the list of the firewall?

If yes, can someone provide me a clear small example on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [access_control](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/access_control.html):

```
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main: 
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,  ip: 127.0.0.1 }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```